# window DOMContentLoaded vs document DOMContentLoaded

Tags: javascript, dom-events, document-ready, domcontentloaded

The modern replacement of the (on)"DOM ready" is the `DOMContentLoaded` event.

You can listen on it on 2 global objects:

- `window` => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event
- `document` => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event

Now I know that the original target of this event is `document` however according to the MDN link above there's also ability to "listen for this event on the Window interface to handle it in the capture or bubbling phases.".

**Is there a particular advantage or a special case when it would be more appropriate or even required to catch the event on the `window` - for either the *capture* or the *bubble up* phase?**

Comment: It seems more like a side-effect of event bubbling than an actual feature.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski in this moment I can only imagine 1 case where you'd want to do that and that is if you need something to be run before some `document` bind, but you can't put your code before - **but** - it does not seem to work this way and the `document` event is ***always*** called first, even though `window` was bound first - https://jsfiddle.net/yzhm8puL/ so maybe it could be used the other way around - if you want to run something after ALL `document`'s `DOMContentLoaded` event listeners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came back to this after some time and it started to make sense:

1. the `Window` listener happens **AFTER** the `Document` event - **because** it **bubbles *FROM*** the **Document**
2. so if you run ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8btogj17/)):

   ```
   window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
     alert("Catching event on window - target: " + event.target.constructor.name);
   });
   ```

   ...the output in the alert will be:

   > Catching event on window - target: **HTMLDocument**

   Which proves it's from Document since `window.constructor.name` is `"Window"`

This is even described [in the Living Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#stop-parsing) which reads (as of 2023-06-20)

> ##### 13.2.7 The end
>
> Once the user agent stops parsing the document, the user agent must run the following steps:
>
> 1...
>
> 6. Queue a global task on the DOM manipulation task source given the Document's relevant global object to run the following substeps:
>
> 1. Set the Document's load timing info's DOM content loaded event start time to the current high resolution time given the Document's relevant global object.
> 2. **Fire an event named [DOMContentLoaded](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#event-domcontentloaded) at the [Document](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#document) object, with its [bubbles](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-event-bubbles) attribute initialized to true.**
> 3. ...

And also [in the `Events` part](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#event-domcontentloaded) of the docs:

> - Event: **DOMContentLoaded**
> - Interface: Event
> - Interesting targets: **Document**
> - Description: **Fired at the [Document](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#document) once the parser has finished**

There is no mention of `DOMContentLoaded` for `window` specifically :-)

### So to answer the main question

The difference is ***when*** you want your handler to ***be executed***.

#### AFTER ALL `document` `DOMContentLoaded` listeners have been executed

=> use `window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ...`

#### Among all other handlers listening to `DOMContentLoaded` on `Document`

=> use `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ...`

*Sidenote: MDN mentions `load` event on the "Document: DOMContentLoaded event" page - that is taken out of context and what they mean is to use `load` event listener on **`Window`** - <del>`Document`</del> does not have a `load` event since it isn't an <del>`Element`...</del>*